# MySQL JOIN and CONCAT issue with data

Tags: mysql, sql

I scraped some data from a website, where I wanted the data to look like this:

```
company_name | location | tags 
----------------------------------
company1     | USA      | tag1, tag2
company2     | China    | tag3, tag4, tag5
```

But instead the scraper pulled data in this format:

```
company_name | location | tags 
----------------------------------
company1     | USA      | tag1
company1     | USA      | tag2
company2     | China    | tag3
company2     | China    | tag4
company2     | China    | tag5
```

How would I turn the current data I have what I want above?

Comment: What version do you have? ... you might be able to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_concat()`:

```
select company_name, location, group_concat(tags separator ', ')
from t
group by company_name, location;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`. For example:

```
select 
  company_name,
  location,
  group_concat(tags) as tags
from t
group by company_name, location
```